# How to delete files from directory using rm -rf?

Tags: linux, centos

I have directory exam with 2 files in it. I need to delete 
files but permission is denied. Even `![rm -rf][1]` command can't delete these
files. I logged in as a root user.

```
# rm -rf exam_a
# rm -rf exam_b
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show the exact permissions. Use the `ls -l` flag for that.

Comment: **ok one minute please**

Comment: Two  more questions: is that really a directory in a local file system? Is that part of the file system really mounted read/write?

Comment: Oh, and please add that information to the question itself using the `edit` button below it. No need for a screenshot, just copy&paste the stuff from the shell as code like you did with the commands.

Comment: also, show "chattr" on these files

Comment: why are you using -r? i think it's for directory

Comment: All files have zero bytes? Strange... One suggestion: try using autocompletion for the file names, just in case we are dealing with some wired utf characters here: type "rm -f e", then hit the [tab] key twice. It should offer the files. Select one (not by typing it, by chosing from the list) and try that.

Comment: Do you have an answer for my question above about the file system situation?

Comment: and: how were those files created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From root user check attributes of files

```
# lsattr
```

if you notice `i` or `a`

```
# man chattr
# chattr -i [filename]
# chattr -a [filename]
```

if it doesn't work reboot system.

Comment: What effect should rebooting of the system have?

Comment: **Yes I had letter i there... Thank you very much.**